# Swearing by Allah's name not to tell a secret but to my mother

Tags: halal-haram, oaths

If I swear by Allah's name not to tell anyone a secret except to my mother, is this haram? Because what if we have to tell our mothers everything?

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in our [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help). If the oath is to tell no one but your mother, then you tell your mother, what is your question in specific?